# Soundcloud Integration with Phonegap App

Tags: cordova, soundcloud

I would like to know how much can I integrate my app with Soundcloud. What I would like to do is integrate and sync with specific users who already have a soundcloud account so that users can access their music from my phonegap app. Is this possible along with the ability to search through their list of sounds to ensure there are no duplicates?

Lastly can someone direct me to where I can find the copyright issues with selling music that are stored on Souncloud

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Soundcloud has javascript API. That should get you started with soundcloud and cordova
http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/guide

Legal notices and copyright notices are in soundcloud's main menu. Did you see them!!
https://soundcloud.com/terms-of-use

https://soundcloud.com/pages/copyright

Comment: Only work for your tracks, not for tracks of others.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible in a couple ways:

1. You have the users login to their soundcloud account via auth0 authentication (redundant) - [Soundcloud Mobile Authentication Widget](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/guide#mobile)
2. Their profile is a public profile in which case they can enter their SC username through a form which would splice into a url string and execute a chain of api requests.

I'd suggest going with the first method as the second method is largely just a hack, would and would require more work. On the other hand, it could make you app a bit more lean.